# Windows On-Screen Keyboard method/api

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I've been trying to send KeyStrokes to a game application, but with no success.
I've tried SendInput, keybd_event, PostMessage and SendMessage but nothing seems to work.

I discovered Windows On-Screen Keyboard work wonders, however.
So I figured I'd take use of this application.

I havn't found much about it, but does it have an API I can use? Or what kind of calls does the program make? Maybe I can replicate it in my app.

Thanks.

Comment: Try sendKeyUP & sendKeyDown , and i really impressed with your questions , i up vote some questions asked by you.